# How to make a currency exchange app with swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I need to make a very simple app in Xcode using Swift. The app needs to be a currency exchange app that can convert 4 types of currencies: dollar, euro, bitcoin, and pound. No back-end coding necessary.

#### Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let rates = [0.9,1.5,1.25,12]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var swap: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var convertToSegmentControl: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var convertedAmountLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencySelectorFrom: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencySelectorTo: UISegmentedControl!
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func convertToSegmentControl(_ sender: Any) {
    if let num = Double(amountTextField.text!) {
        switch currencySelectorFrom.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num
            let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountLabel)
            convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
        case 1:
            let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num
            let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountLabel)
            convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
        case 2:
            let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num
            let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountLabel)
            convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
        case 3:
            let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num
            let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountLabel)
            convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
        default:
            break

        }
    }else{
        convertedAmountLabel.text = ""
            print("Could not convert user input to double.")
    }

}

}
```

#### Problem:

On lines 27, 31, 35, and 39, I get an error. It reads:

> 'Value of type 'Double' has no member 'text'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: 1. This is way too broad of a request. 2. There's no question here. What are you asking? If it's where to start, that's not appropriate for the site.

Comment: @Carcigenicate How do I make it? Just generally, how would I program the converter?

Comment: That would require a fairly large tutorial to be written up for you to answer that. Get a start on this yourself, Andy post back when you have a specific question.

Comment: Alright, I just added my code to the question above and have started the project. Now I am stuck. Sorry for not being clear the first time... this is my first time *ever* on stack overflow, and my first question ever posted. Anyways, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is you do `let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num` which assigns a double to `convertedAmountLabel`, then you write `convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded`. As the error points out, Doubles don't have `.text` fields. You're overwriting the label object with a local double.

Comment: So... how do I fix that? Do I just delete the `.text` after `convertedAmountLabel`?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you're intent is, so I can't say. Why do you create a label called `convertedAmountLabel`, then create a new variable later with the same name?

Comment: Can't you just get rid of all the useless `let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num`s and just change the `rounded` lines to `let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", rates[0] * num)`? Why even write `let convertedAmountLabel = rates[0] * num` in the first place?

Comment: Well, the `convertedAmountLabel` variable works like this: There are 4 buttons. Each button is labeled with a currency. There is also a text field that the user will tap on and type in a number. The user will then tap on the currency that they are converting from, and then tap another button that will be what the user is converting to. The `rates[0]` works like this: my app will just use a static number: a ratio. For example, the U.S. dollar is worth 0.9 Euro, so (if I was converting $ to €) the app would take the number of dollars and multiply it by 0.9. That's why I wrote what I wrote.

Comment: I understand the labels, but why are you creating a new variable with the same name as the label, and giving it a double? That's the problem. Try the changes I suggested in the comment above.

Comment: Okay. I will try them

Comment: Oh... my... goodness.

Comment: I understand. XD How could I make such a stupid mistake. Thanks. It works.

Comment: See my answer. The entire `switch` is also unnecessary.

Comment: Np. Glad I could help. Just some advice when you post on here next: post all relevant information and code from the start. The more you make people guess what you want, the less likely they are to help you. You're lucky I was bored on my break or I would have swiped right past your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know Swift, so excuse any syntax errors I introduce.

Your entire `switch` is unnecessary. If you look at the code in each case, they're all the same, which shouldn't be the case.

Replace your entire code with this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let rates = [0.9,1.5,1.25,12]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var swap: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var convertToSegmentControl: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var convertedAmountLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencySelectorFrom: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencySelectorTo: UISegmentedControl!
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func convertToSegmentControl(_ sender: Any) {
    if let num = Double(amountTextField.text!) {
        let cur = currencySelectorFrom.selectedSegmentIndex
        let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", rates[cur] * num)
        convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded

    }else{
        convertedAmountLabel.text = ""
            print("Could not convert user input to double.")
    }

}

}
```

This is untested, as I wrote this on my phone, but it should work. Notice how I just index `rates` directly instead of putzing around with a `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were accidentally trying to assign a `double` to a `UITextField`

I guessed at your intention and came up with the following....

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let rates = [0.9,1.5,1.25,12]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var swap: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var convertToSegmentControl: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var convertedAmountLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencySelectorFrom: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var currencySelectorTo: UISegmentedControl!
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func convertToSegmentControl(_ sender: Any) {
        if let num = Double(amountTextField.text!) {
            switch currencySelectorFrom.selectedSegmentIndex{
            case 0:
            // Renamed this from `convertedAmountLabel` to `convertedAmountValue` (likewise for the other cases)
                let convertedAmountValue = rates[0] * num
            // This line of code consumes the `double` `convertedAmountValue`
                let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountValue)
                convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
            case 1:
                let convertedAmountValue = rates[0] * num
                let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountValue)
                convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
            case 2:
                let convertedAmountValue = rates[0] * num
                let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountValue)
                convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
            case 3:
                let convertedAmountValue = rates[0] * num
                let rounded = String(format: "%.2f", convertedAmountValue)
                convertedAmountLabel.text = rounded
            default:
                break

            }
        }else{
            convertedAmountLabel.text = ""
            print("Could not convert user input to double.")
        }

    }

}
```